# How to open NTFS binary image on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, backup, ntfs

Basically I have binary image of NTFS partition made with WinHex. WinHex is able to open such files and show directory structure, besides hex editing. Is there tool with similar capabilities on Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: I solved the issue with WinHEX under Wine :) That's because I was not able to correctly mount my partition image - it was not recognized correctly. But WinHEX handled it very well. If you need, I can provide error messages etc.

Comment: WinHex is catastrophic under Wine...when I go in as regular user, OpenDisk works but I have no permission to open the disk. When I go in as `root`, the Open Disk window does not appear and the whole application is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about about a tool like WinHex, but you can mount a [binary image of the partition by doing the following](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device):

If sda.img is the binary image file, then...

Get the partition layout of the image

```
$ sudo fdisk -lu sda.img
...
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
...
  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
sda.img1   *          56     6400000     3199972+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Calculate the offset from the start of the image to the partition start

```
Sector size * Start = (in the case) 56 * 512 = 28672
```

Mount it on /dev/loop0 using the offset

```
sudo losetup -o 28672 /dev/loop0 sda.img
```

Now the partition resides on /dev/loop0. You can fsck it, mount it etc

```
sudo fsck -fv /dev/loop0
sudo mount /dev/loop0 /mnt
```

Unmount

```
sudo umount /mnt
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
```